# Finding an item in a tree in common lisp

Tags: tree, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function that can find an item in a tree, similar to the built-in `find` function for sequences. The call could look like `(find-in-tree item tree :test test-fn :key key-fn)`. The hyperspec says the item passed to `find` can be any lisp object (that is, "any Lisp datum"), but the tree I have in mind is not the usual Lisp binary cons tree. The tree, call it a multitree, would be a (possibly recursive or dotted) list of atoms or lists. An example is `(find-in-tree '(1 2) '(1 (2) nil (3 (1 2)) . 4) :test #'equal)` => (1 2) or some non-nil value.

In looking around I came across some interesting code at http://lisptips.com/post/43404489000/the-tree-walkers-of-cl which, with suitable adaptations, does seem to work for the standard cons tree:

```
(defun find-in-tree (item tree &key (test #'eql))
  (catch 'find-in-tree
         (subst-if t (constantly nil) tree 
                   :key (lambda (element)
                          (when (funcall test element item)
                            (throw 'find-in-tree element))))
         nil))
```

However, I'm not sure how to adapt this (or build a recursive function) for a multitree.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `(or (find-in-tree ... (car tree) ...) (find-in-tree ... (cdr tree) ...))`, (with some precautions for the case when you search for nil?)

Comment: Yup, that fixes it for atoms, thanks.

Comment: you need to come up with a definition of tree and some actual examples. Otherwise we have to guess. Also it's unclear why you don't want to check the CDR. Just looking at the CAR makes no tree traversal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this. Use a local function for the recursion. From there one can escape from the recursion using `return-from` once the item is found.

```
CL-USER> (defun find-in-tree (item tree &key (test #'eql))                             
           (labels ((find-in-tree-aux (tree)                                           
                      (cond ((funcall test item tree)                                  
                             (return-from find-in-tree tree))                          
                            ((consp tree)                                              
                             (find-in-tree-aux (car tree))                             
                             (find-in-tree-aux (cdr tree))))))                         
             (find-in-tree-aux tree)))
FIND-IN-TREE                                                                           
CL-USER> (find-in-tree 3 '((2 (4 3)) 5))
3                                                                                      
CL-USER> (find-in-tree 12 '((2 (4 3)) 5))
NIL                                                                                    
CL-USER> (find-in-tree "foo" '(("bar" ("baz")) "foo") :test #'equalp)
"foo"                                                                   
CL-USER> (find-in-tree 6 '((2 (4 3 . 6)) 5))
6
```

and

```
CL-USER 14 > (defun find-in-tree (item tree &key (test #'eql) (key #'identity))
              (labels ((find-in-tree-aux (tree)                                   
                         (cond ((funcall test item (funcall key tree))
                                (return-from find-in-tree tree))
                               ((consp tree)
                                (find-in-tree-aux (car tree))
                                (find-in-tree-aux (cdr tree))))))
                (find-in-tree-aux tree)))
FIND-IN-TREE

CL-USER 15 > (find-in-tree "foo" '(("a" 10)
                                   (("b" 20)
                                    ("foo" 300))
                                   ("c" 40))
                           :test #'equalp
                           :key (lambda (i)
                                  (when (consp i)
                                    (first i))))
("foo" 300)
```

**Node as a list of trees**

```
CL-USER 1 > (defun find-in-tree (item tree &key (test #'eql) (key #'identity))
              (labels ((find-in-tree-aux (tree)                                   
                         (cond ((funcall test item (funcall key tree))
                                (return-from find-in-tree tree))
                               ((listp tree)
                                (mapc #'find-in-tree-aux tree)
                                nil))))
                (find-in-tree-aux tree)))
FIND-IN-TREE
```

Comment: I better understand how to use an aux function now, thank you. But it still needs to avoid testing the cdr: `(find-in-tree '((2 3)) '(1 (2 3)) :test #'equal)` => ((2 3)). This seems to be the same issue with coredump's comment above.

Comment: @davypough In that case, the return-from exits from `find-in-tree`, which is at the zeroth level of recursion. This is different from the case where you return normally from each recursive call, and where the result must be propagated back up the call chain, and where you have to cut the search manually with `or`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: @daypough: for a cons tree it does the right thing. If you have another tree in mind, you need to define what a node is, what its content is and what it's successors are.

Comment: OK, but the "cons tree" interpretation of a tree then seems quite unintuitive to me. In the analogous sequence operation `(find '((2 3)) '(1 (2 3)) :test #'equal)` => NIL, ((2 3)) is not an element of the sequence (1 (2 3)), but is an element of the tree (1 (2 3)). However, it looks like I can find-in-tree (using my interpretation) by using an aux function to only test the car of each tree. The enclosing main function would then test the input tree for item equality before turning it into a list and passing it to the aux?

Comment: @davypough what is your argument? a tree or a list of trees? You need to define your tree to get rid of the confusion. Btw. cons trees are simple binary trees with cons cells as nodes and car and cdr as successors. That's very intuitive.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig: Appreciate your explanation that cons trees are binary trees, which is obvious now since everything is built out of cons cells with two fields (car & cdr). Your third find-in-tree function realizes my "lists of lists" intention, and works for me.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig: Here's an instance of where the third function doesn't work as I would like: `(find-in-tree 3 '(1 2 . 3))` => error. Do you see downsides to a different approach: `(defun search-in-tree (item tree) (search (format nil "~S" item) (format nil "~S" tree)))`?